# Reading specific excel sheet into Python pandas dataframe without loading the whole workbook

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

pd.read_excel(filepath, sheetname) and openpyxl.Workbook(filepath) load the whole workbook. I have a 30MB file on a server and it takes a long time to load. I was wondering if there was a method to load a specific sheet as a pandas dataframe without opening the whole workbook.

I have looked into a couple of methods. Most recently, converting the workbook to a .zip and reading the .xml files. I know that people have suggested using lxml. I'm not sure how to go from here.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try pd.read_excel(io, sheetname="sheet1") where you can give the sheet name? Not sure though if it works any better..

Comment: Yes, pd.read_excel loads the whole workbook and then the specified sheet, and not a specific sheet. Reading the whole workbook takes too long. I was wondering if there's a way to read a specific sheet within a workbook.

Comment: Not sure you saw this argument "sheetname" within the read_excel() function. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I have used sheetname in the pd.read_excel function. I believe that loads all sheets before it parses to a specific one.

Comment: I believe openpyxl gets a lot faster if you specify `read_only=True`, as in `openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath, data_only=True, read_only=True)`. That may help. Don't know if it still reads the whole file though.

Comment: Still reads the whole file, but this might be the answer I'm looking for. Thanks!